# harmonic maps from cone to $S^2$ locally lipschitz?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Are the harmonic maps from a 2-dimensional cone to $S^2$ locally lipschitz or Holder continuous?

Answer (score 2):

They are localy Holder continuous. 
There is a map $\phi$ from the plane to the cone which is
bijective, the inverse is Holder, and $\phi$ is conformal except one point.
This map can be written explicitly.
Let your map be $f$. Composition $g=f\circ\phi$ is harmonic except one point, so by
removable singularity theorem it is harmonic everywhere, thus locally Holder.
So your map $f=g\circ\phi^{-1}$ is locally Holder. The Holder exponent depends on
the opening of the cone.

Comment: :Just as you have said before. Take the cone as a sector with total angel $\alpha<2\pi$. Then $\phi^{-1}$ is $z\mapsto z^{\pi/\alpha}$. It seems to me this map is also locally Lipshcitz(hence every harmonic map is locally lipschitz).

Comment: In your question you did not specify the range of $\alpha$. In general, this map is Holder.